# Where do I install SSRS?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, iis-7.5

I have a web server which has IIS and that has connection to my database server where all DBS are installed.

All of my application logic is in my application server.  application server stores all of the business workflow system

Where do i install SSRS which I need to display? Should i install it on a web server or on application or databsae server?

I am going to use reportviewer to display SSRS reports.
I have license to use MS SQL DB.
Please recommend where SSRS need to go and how I would make SSRS reports available to my web application?

DBs are MS SQL 2008 R2.  SSRS is 2008.  IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

When you install Reporting Services, it adds a couple of databases to your SQL Server installation.  These store the reports, subscriptions, configuration, etc..

Prior to 2008, there was a dependency on IIS to serve the reports from a web service.  However this was changed in 2008 and Reporting Services now handles HTTP by itself without relying on IIS.

Comment: where do i deploy the reports? in the database?

Comment: You can do it in bulk directly from Visual Studio and they will end up in the SQL database.  You can also navigate to the web interface and deploy them individually from there.  I think you need to read some documentation on getting started.  Maybe this video will help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/Video/dd370686

Comment: Thanks. it was useful. so it's all done via VS.  I dont understand where the reports server website is. i have installed reporting server from database installation section but i can't navigate to the website. how do i find what the url is?

Answer (score 0):

When you install SQL Server on your Database Server you get an option to Configure and Install Reporting Services too. It is essentially a database on your Database Server that has information about all the reports like.

a) How many times they were run
b) which user has run the most number of reports
c) Execution times of reports etc.

Note: The above information is stored in Views.

Once Reporting Services is installed you can check this out by navigating to localhost/Reports.

Regarding using the Report Viewer Control to display the reports. There are a certain steps that you can follow to make the reports available through your application.

1) Add references to the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms DLL's to your application.

2) Defining the Credentials to authenticate users to access the Report Server (Remote Processing)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

3) Working with the Report Viewer Control itself

Comment: ok thanks.  does it mean that i need reporting services installed on the database server?  is that all or do i need to do anything else too?

Comment: Yes. You need to install Reporting Services on the Database Server.